# Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to find all elements that has a special attribute value.

Here is the div I need to find (I have many of them..)

```
<div imageId='imageN'>...
```

I simply need to loop through the divs which have `imageId='imageN'`

Comment: I'd recommend using `class="imageN"` for the sake of valid HTML.  Either that or `data-imageId="imageN"` for the sake of valid HTML5.  With the former, you'd be able to use the class selector.

Comment: Andy, the reason behind this is, these divs are added dynamically from code-behind and have different ImageIds but same class'.

Comment: u can have multiple classes `class="image imageN"` if that helps.

Comment: Why not select on the classname then if they already have the same class?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
$('div[imageId="imageN"]').each(function() {
    // `this` is the div
});
```

To check for the sole existence of the attribute, no matter which value, you could use ths selector instead: `$('div[imageId]')`

Comment: @ThiefMaster - If the attribute value is not constant, (i.e it will vary) then how to find it?

Comment: a couple of questions: 1- what about other elements ... 2- what about other values ... I might have the attribute **data-food** on many elements: div's, img's and a td's, where each has a different value.

Comment: @ParthoGanguly You use a variable this way: $('div[imageId="' + variableName + '"]')

Comment: This solution doesn't really answer the title of this page. You are searching for elements that are divs. A proper solution is one that is agnostic of the actual element.

Answer (score 181):

Although it doesn't precisely answer the question, I landed here when searching for a way to get the collection of elements (potentially different tag names) that simply had a given attribute name (without filtering by attribute value). I found that the following worked well for me:

```
$("*[attr-name]")
```

Update:
It appears that the asterisk is not required, i.e. based on some basic tests, the following seems to be equivalent to the above (thanks to Matt for pointing this out):

```
$("[attr-name]")
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Quite possibly...I didn't check the performance aspect (wasn't an important factor for my use at the time).

Comment: Is there any difference between that and `$("[attr-name]")`? (i.e. no `*`)

Comment: Yes there is certain difference between them. star notation raise error on firefox!!!! (Unescaped ...)

Comment: adding to this, you can also include an attributes value, eg: `$("[data-toggle='modal']")`

Comment: this should be the correct answer because "all ELEMENTS" is not the same as "all DIV". The selected answer gets only div elements while this gets everything including inputs, lists and so on. If performance matters, just limite where you whant to find the elements like $("[data-toggle='modal']", $(body))

Answer (score 16):

It's not called a tag; what you're looking for is called an html attribute.

```
$('div[imageId="imageN"]').each(function(i,el){
  $(el).html('changes');
  //do what ever you wish to this object :) 
});
```

Comment: how would you go about finding the inverse?

Answer (score 6):

You can use partial value of an attribute to detect a DOM element using (^) sign.
For example you have divs like this:

```
<div id="abc_1"></div>
<div id="abc_2"></div>
<div id="xyz_3"></div>
<div id="xyz_4"></div>...
```

You can use the code:

```
var abc = $('div[id^=abc]')
```

This will return a DOM array of divs which have id starting with `abc`:

```
<div id="abc_1"></div>
<div id="abc_2"></div>
```

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/mCuWS/

Answer (score 6):

Use string concatenation.
Try this:

```
$('div[imageId="'+imageN +'"]').each(function() {
    $(this);   
});
```