# How do I find the number of 'complete' images?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to find the number of images within a specific element(div) that have the property 'complete'(as in the browser has completed loading them).

I've been stumbling around this for over an hour now and my brain is completely fried. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958081/find-all-elements-with-a-certain-attribute-in-jquery

Comment: I’ve reinstated the edits and locked the post to stop the constant rollbacks. The `complete` tag serves no purpose here so definitely should not be re-added, and the changes to the question were a clear improvement (making your question clearer and easier for future visitors to follow).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your immediate question to find images with the `complete` property, you could use this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("div_id"),
    images = container.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    completeImages = [],
    j = images.length,
    i, cur;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    cur = images[i];
    if (cur.complete) {
        completeImages.push(cur);
    }
}
```

After this code is run, `completeImages` is an array of `<img>` elements that have the `complete` property as `true`.

With jQuery, you could use:

```
var images = $("#div_id").find("img").filter(function () {
    return $(this).prop("complete");
    // or
    return this.complete;
});
```

In this case, `images`, is a jQuery object (array-like object) of `<img>` elements that have the `complete` property as `true`.

Instead of checking the `complete` property, another option is to use the `load` event to detect when they load and set special data for them:

```
$("#div_id").on("load", "img", function () {
    $(this).data("image-complete", true);
});
```

and to find out which/how many are loaded:

```
$("#div_id").find("img").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data("image-complete");
});
```

Note that the `load` event isn't fully supported/reliable with `<img>`s: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ - scroll down to the "Caveats of the load event when used with images" section.

Comment: Thanks, a lot of useful info here. `.load` is what I had originally tried, but ran into issues because the images are being added dynamically so any image that has been cached will not register with `.load`. I ended up using the `.filter` method and it works great.

It seems like the more I know the more I need to learn... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could also recreate the same behavior using classes -

```
$("img").load(function(){
  $(this).addClass('complete');
});
```

Now whenever you want to see how many images have been loaded you can just use this selector -

```
$("img.complete").length
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work with images that are loaded initially? The images I am working with are dynamically added which is why I am using the 'complete' property instead of `.load`. When I tried using `.load` chached images were not affected/counted