# Target an element by its anchor title in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to hide the home menu item from my navigation menu and only display it when the mobile navigation menu is toggled. Is there a way that I can select the li item by anchor title (home) and add the active class to it when toggled, like I have done to the other elements? or could I do this with css somehow? I'm using a wordpress nav menu so I can't add a specific class to it. Many thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
    $logo = $('.logo'),
    $menulink = $('.menu-link');

    $menulink.click(function() {
    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
    $menu.toggleClass('active');
    $logo.toggleClass('active');
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: "Anchor title"? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958081/find-all-elements-with-a-certain-attribute-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6):

This will get the anchor with the title of "home"

```
$('a[title="home"]')
```

So you would use

```
$('a[title="home"]').toggleClass('active');
```

See the [W3C selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) for more on this syntax

Answer (score 2):

You know you can target an anchor attributed of a title with only css ?

```
a[title^="Some title text"] { color: red; }
```

For targeting with javascript --> [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266631/selecting-elements-without-jquery)

> var links = top.document.getElementsByTagName('a'); var result = [];
>   var linkcount = links.length; for ( var i = 0; i < linkcount; i++) {
>       if (links[i].getAttribute('title') === 'some title text here') {
>           result.push(links[i]);
>       } }

For targeting with jQuery  --> user John Conde answered before or [Get element by title jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery)

> $('a[title="Some title text"]')

Also, try a search on the net with your question -->  [google for an example](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&newwindow=1&q=javascript%20select%20element%20by%20title)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
    $logo = $('.logo'),
    $menulink = $('.menu-link');
    $homelink = $('li[title*="home"]'); // remove the * if u have more with "*home*"

    $menulink.click(function() {
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
        $logo.toggleClass('active');
        $homelink.toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```