# How to check html element with specific attribute value is present or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check whether an element with specific attribute value is present inside a div tag.

For example,

```
<div id='testdiv'>
    <a dir='hello' href='#' ></a>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btn' />
```

Here is my Jquery.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   if(/*Here I need the condition to check whether, `a` tag with attribute `dir` with value `hello` is present inside `div` */)
   {
       alert(present);
   }
}
```

Please advice dear friends as I am beginner in jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Combine the solutions to these questions: [Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4958081) and [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31044).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
   if ( $('#testdiv a[dir="hello"]').length ) {
       alert(present);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   if($("div").find("a[dir=hello]").length == 1)
   {
       alert(present);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
       if ( $('#testdiv a').attr('dir') == 'hello' ) {
           alert('1111111');
       }
        else
            alert('222');
    });
```

[Also see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFyWR/11/)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help learn how to format code properly.