# How to find a div element by attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="contentPane">
    ...
    ...
    <div guidedhelpid="friendsuggestions">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

I need to do some changes in **guidedhelpid**. For example, $(#theElem).remove()

Note: I can use jQuery upon request.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496427/how-to-get-elements-by-attribute-selector-w-native-javascript-w-o-queryselector) could help you to make your own JS function ppure javascript no jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958081/find-all-elements-with-a-certain-attribute-value-in-jquery)

Comment: I recommend to use `data-*` attributes so that your HTML is valid.

Comment: `guidehelpid` is not a valid html attribute. What do you want to remove, the attribute, the value of it or the whole `div` element? Completely agree with @FelixKling . Didn't you find that out already? I found [this validator report through google](https://sitevalidator.com/html/error/attribute-guidedhelpid-not-allowed-on-element-div-at-this-point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (upon request), then you can do `$('div[guidedhelpid=friendsuggestions]')`

For pure javascript, you can use this function to return an array of elements that contain that attribute name:

```
function getElementsByAttributeName(attr) {
    var arr_elms = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        elms_len = arr_elms.length,
        return_arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elms_len; i++) {
       if(arr_elms[i].getAttribute(attr) != null){  
           return_arr.push(arr_elems[i]);
       }
    }

    return return_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if using Jquery it is simply possible by

```
   var div = $('div[guidedhelpid="friendsuggestions"]');
```