# Finding elements in HTML with certain attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following HTML

```
<Something attribute="" id="top">
    <Something attribute="child" id="child"></Something>
</Something>
```

I am trying to get a jquery object representing the second `Something` element.  I am trying the following query (as suggested in this question [Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958081/find-all-elements-with-a-certain-attribute-value-in-jquery)) in my browser console

```
$("Something[attribute='child']")
```

But I seem to be getting the same empty array each time, however the following works

```
$("Something[attribute='']")
```

This returns me an array of one element representing the first `Something` element

Comment: `Something[attribute='child']` -> Selects `something` that has the attribute `attribute='child'` | `Something [attribute='child']` -> selects `something` that has **a child** that has the attribute `attribute='child'`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Wait I don't see the difference between those two..

Comment: The space. That is **the** difference

Comment: I didn't have any space in my queries though...

Comment: Unable to reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/rgzgw4bo/

Comment: Turns out the error was that my browser had cached the result from the previous page and didnt update....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a DOM array of divs which have id (attribute) "stack":

```js
var stack = $('div[id=stack]');

var result = " ";

$(stack).each(function(index, element){
    result = element.id + result;
});

document.body.innerHTML = result
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="stack"></div>
<div id="stack"></div>
<div id="notstack"></div>
<div id="notstack"></div>
```