# Finding the value of an attribute of an HTML object given the value of another attribute of the same object (JS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the name value of a message whose num value is already known so that I can store it and the name as separate variables. For example, if I want to get the name value of message 5, I'd have to go into the source code to find it when I'd rather just be able to fetch it using jQuery, but I'm inexperienced and have been unable to find a way to do so. I want to do something like:

```
$("name") where $("num") = 1
```

but that syntax is wrong, obviously.

Here is the div that contains the two attributes:

```
<div class="msg" num="1" name="923103870">
```

How can I get the name using jQuery if I don't already know it?

I know how to find the element that contains num=1, but only the whole element. How do I extract only the name attribute rather than the whole element?

I know this question is very basic, but Googling hasn't given me a good answer. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: did you mean name attribute and value attribute respectively?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of the name attribute given that I know the value of the num attribute. Sorry, realized that was unclear.

Comment: In order for people to assist you will want to post the minimal code to duplicate the issue [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all elements with a certain attribute value in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958081/find-all-elements-with-a-certain-attribute-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var divName = $("[num = 1]").attr("name")
```

Assuming you want to put the number 1 in the hard code, you can do as the sample above. Now, if the number is a variable that is filled through the code and it's called x, try this:

```
var divName = $("[num = " + x + "]").attr("name")
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Given you meant name attribute and value attribute respectively:

**Using Jquery:**

to get the name attr value:

```
let whatIWant = $('.msg[num="1"]').attr("name")
```

to get the whole jquery object:

```
let elem = $('.msg[num="1"][name]')
```

if you need the dom element from the above jquery object:

```
let htmlElem = elem[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selectors to get the name attribute of any elements that have a `num` value of 1. This particular solution is good for multiple elements that may have a `num` value of 1.

You didn't specify any elements, so I assume you want any that match the criteria:

```
//x is taking the place of your number (assuming it's in the code)
let x = 1
//aggregate elements into an array using spread and the CSS selector []
//which targets attributes
//use the value of X to gather the elements
let valueEls = [...$(`[num="${x}"]`)]
//initialize empty names container
let names = []
//push the name of each element into the names container
valueEls.forEach(el => names.push($(el).attr('name')))
console.log(names)
```

Comment: `forEach` is actually faster than `map`: https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS

Comment: If you click the link, it's a reference to jQuery's `map`, not `Array.prototype.map` :).

Comment: That link is a reference to native JS Array.prototype.map, not to jQuery.

Comment: My apologies! Hmm it would be interesting to see a speed comparison between jQuery's `map` and using `spread` and then a `forEach`.

Comment: I think for the purposes of this question, the difference is negligible, unless they have 50k elements, and then the perf hit is going to be in the DOM, not the array manipulation.